Does every cardinal have a successor without choice?
In ZF, given a cardinal $\kappa$ is there always a cardinal $\mu$ such that $\kappa < \mu$ and there is no cardinal between $\kappa$ and $\mu$? (here by cardinal i mean equivalence class of sets up to bijection).

In ZF (or even ZFC), can you even talk about "equivalence class of sets up to bijection"? The collection of all singletons is a proper class. In ZF, cardinals are usually defined to be certain ordinals instead.

@ArturoMagidin You can indirectly talk about classes. We can avoid mentioning them for the purposes of my question tho. My question can be rephrased as: Given a set $\kappa$ is there a set $\mu$ such that there is an injection from $\kappa$ into $\mu$ but there is no set $X$ such that $X$ is not bijective to either $\kappa$ or $\mu$ but there is an injection from $\kappa$ into $X$ and an injection from $X$ to $\mu$?

Forgot to mention in my comment: also require $\kappa$ not to be bijective to $\mu$.

@ArturoMagidin you can do it using Scott's trick, which only needs the axiom of foundation

It may be worth pointing out that there may be several, incomparable, successors. For instance, under (say) determinacy, both $\mathbb R+\aleph_1$ and $\mathbb R/E_0$ are successors of $\mathbb R$, where $E_0$ is Vitali's equivalence relation.

(See here.)

@AndrésE.Caicedo : On slide 6 of your cited presentation is stated that, while it is open in ZF whether there are infinitely many incomparable cardinals (ICs),  Feldman–Orhon showed that in ZF there must be $n$ ICs for each natural $n$. Naïvely, I would think that, if there are not infinitely many ICs, then there are only finitely many—say at most $n$ of them. But, by Feldman–Orhon, there are $n+1$ ICs. Is Choice somehow buried in this reasoning?

@JohnBentin The question is whether there is an infinite collection of cardinals, no two of which are comparable. It is not clear whether the examples from the Feldman–Orhon paper can be made compatible: say $T_n$ is the collection of $n$ incomparable cardinals they exhibit. For $n< m$, the cardinals in $T_m$ are different from those in $T_n$, and it is not clear whether we can do something to their construction to ensure that either $T_n$ is always a subcollection of $T_m$, or at least $T_n\cup T_m$ consists of pairwise incomparable cardinals.

Yes. This is Problem 13 of Chapter 11 in Jech's Axiom of Choice.
The idea is that if $A$ is any Dedekind infinite set, then $A+\aleph(A)$ is such a successor for $A$. Here $\aleph(A)$ is the Hartogs number of $A$, which is the least ordinal which doesn't inject into $A$.
Note that we can define the notion of successor in several different ways, and that will make a big difference. Jech does that around that part of the book.

This doesn't sound right. Let $A$ be an infinite Dedekind-finite set. Then $\aleph(A) = \omega$. However the successor of $A$ is $A+1$ not $A+\omega$.

Sorry, that should say Dedekind infinite, yes.
